# Can't find file to send file as attachment in python

Tags: python, email, attachment, mime, smtplib

I found this code from another website repository and its used to send emails using python and attach's a file as well. It encodes the file in to base64 brfore sending it. I've tested the code before using an '.xlsx' file and it was sent with out a problem. But now the program doesnt send it for some reason. The file is in the same folder as the code.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

fromaddr = "FROM EMAIL"
toaddr = "TO EMAIL"

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "SUBJECT"

body = "MESSAGE"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = "05-11-2016 - Saturday.xlsx"
attachment = open("05-11-2016 - Saturday", "rb")

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "PASSWORD")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

When i run it ths is the error that is outputted:

```
line 21, in <module>
    attachment = open("05-11-2016 - Saturday", "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '05-11-2016 - Saturday'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't it be `open('05-11-2016 - Saturday.xlsx', 'rb')`?

Comment: When i did that the message got sent but it doesn't have an extension. So it was a file without an extension

Comment: btw, thank you for the hint, I just tried to modify and use your script and it works :) maybe will help for something :)

Answer (score 1):

you have defined `filename` in the line above - so why don't you use it? :)
(you forgot the extension 'xlsx' in the `open` statement)

You now have learned the usefullnes of the DRY-principle:
http://wiki.c2.com/?DontRepeatYourself

By typing it twice, you can change the filename definition and not notice, that the `open` uses another file...

Comment: I've tried this as well and it sends the message but without the xlsx file extension.

Comment: well, the error you printed was "File not found", which has the reason in the wrong filename. And with the right filename the file is sent, but the recipient sees its name without the extension? This has nothing to do with finding the local file, but must be a setting of the sendmail-script. Is it the right file, that gets sent (try renaming it in .xlsx and open it)? Maybe if you change the `part.add_header(...)` to some different string, you will see what happens...?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code using my credentials and made a small txt file in the same directory as the code to replicate your conditions. Here's what you need to modify:

```
filename = "ExplicitFileName.txt"
attachment = open("/USE/COMPLETE/PATH/TO/FILE/ExplicitFileName.txt", "rb")
```

Or as Ilja pointed out the DRY principle you could do it like this:

```
filename = "ExplicitFileName.txt"
attachment = open("/COMPLETE/PATH/TO/FILE/" + filename, "rb")
```

Both of these will work just fine.